# How to update recyclerview from firebase realtime database for a chat app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using recyclerview and firebase realtime database together to allow user to send messages to other users.When a message is sent I need to start that activity again to reload the updates.Is there anyway to do this automatically so that when the user clicks on send the message is displayed directly.

**Action when send button is clicked**

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String message = messageBox.getText().toString();
                if (message.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(privatemessageactivity.this, "You cant send an empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{


                    messagedref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.exists()){
                                messagedref.setValue(true);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });



                    Map<String,Object> mymessage = new HashMap<>();
                    mymessage.put("Image",myImage);
                    mymessage.put("Message",message);
                    sendmessageref.push().setValue(mymessage);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Action to retrieve the data**

```
sendmessageref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        MessageClass ld = snapshot1.getValue(MessageClass.class);
                        list.add(ld);
                    }

                    adapter = new MessageAdapter(list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**My adapter class and my ViewHolder class**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>{

        private List<MessageClass> list;

        public MessageAdapter(List<MessageClass> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messagelayout,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            MessageClass ld = list.get(position);
            holder.message.setText(ld.getMessage());

            if (!ld.getImage().equals("noimage")){
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(ld.getImage()).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }else{
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView message;
            CircleImageView circleImageView;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagesmessage);
                circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagespp);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole purpose of using Firebase is that you **don't** have to explicitly reload the messages. If you use `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, Firebase will keep listening for changes on the server, and will call your `onDataChange` again if there as any changes.

So a common way to keep your message list up to date is:

```
adapter = new MessageAdapter(list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

sendmessageref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        list.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
            MessageClass ld = snapshot1.getValue(MessageClass.class);
            list.add(ld);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

The changes:

- Uses `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` so that it gets called both for the initial data and when there are changes.
- Create and assign the adapter outside of `onDataChange`, since you'll want to set the adapter only once, and then update its data.
- Clear the list in `onDataChange`, since we'll now get called multiple times, and each time we get a full `DataSnapshot` of all the relevant data.
- Notify the adapter of the new data, with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so that it can refresh the UI,.
- Implement `onCancelled`, because it's a bad practice to ignore possible errors.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffeleb What you said worker fine but their was one of error.When I send a message all the previous messages get loaded again.So if I send “hi” and after that if I send “how are you” it will be shown as hi hi how are you.It loads the first message again.

Comment: That is indeed how this code works. If you want more fine-grained control over updates to the UI, consider using a `ChildEventListener`.